# SharedAccessSignature and img HTML tags

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, azure

I've got some thumbnails locked away in Azure. I create a shared access signature:

```
var policy = new SharedAccessPolicy
{
    Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Read,
    SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
};
return blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);
```

and then push these urls into img tags.

```
<img src="@Html.Raw(Model.ThumbnailUrl)"></img>
```

However they render really inconsistently. Sometimes none, sometimes one, sometimes all, etc......
Funny thing is that if you copy the url from the "broken" image and go to it.... you get the image.

Anyone know what might cause this problem?

Comment: Try using chrome developer tools / network tab to determine what image response actually looks like. Look at the output html. Does @Html.Raw(Model.ThumbnailUrl) produce a valid url at all times?

Comment: thanks for the heads up on the network tab. Every single url i've examined has been fine, the fact that I can paste it into a new tab and get the file suggests that. I have considered though that it might be worth testing: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1), just in-case ;)

Comment: Doing DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-x) is the recommended approach for shared access signature start time as it takes care of clock skewness on your local computer. Generally speaking, you should keep this value to -15 or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gaurav Mantri suggested I changed the code to:

```
var policy = new SharedAccessPolicy
{
    Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Read,
    SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-15),
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(45)
};
```

and everything is now lovely. Seems like it was a small timing issue between the two machines.